# How to create a custom view in the header of a form

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I would like to know if its possible to create something like the image below.

[image]

I guess I have to create a custom view but any clue on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a UITableView on the screen, you can achieve this by creating a custom table header view:

1. Create a subclass of `UIView` -> `CustomTableHeaderView`
2. Add a button inside it:

   ```
   class CustomTableHeaderView: UIView {
       var rightButton: UIButton
       override init(frame: CGRect) {
           rightButton = UIButton()
           let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 100
           // this is hardcoded for cimplicity, it's better to setup auto layout constraints here
           rightButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.width - buttonWidth, width: buttonWidth, height: 50)
           rightButton.setTitle("My button", forState: .Normal)
           // other configuration

           super.init(frame: frame)
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
   ```

   }

   3. In your view controller (or any other place where you initialise a table view, set your custom view as a `tableHeaderView`:

   `tableView.tableHeaderView = CustomTableHeaderView(frame: frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 10))`